# Jquery Toggle Table Column Using a Better Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with around 30 columns and the idea is to let the user select which columns to be hidden or shown. The reason for this is to let them select which columns will be visible when they print.

To tackle this problem, I have assigned a class name to each column and i'm using jQuery's toggle function. This works fine, but I was wondering if there is a better way to go about it that is more efficient and cleaner than what I am currently using. I have a separate function for each column and my code looks like this:

**jQuery**

```
function tablecolumn1toggle(){
    $(".column1").toggle();
}

function tablecolumn2toggle(){
    $(".column2").toggle();
}

function tablecolumn3toggle(){
    $(".column3").toggle();
}
```

**HTML** Simplified
        toggle column 1
        toggle column 2
        toggle column 3

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="points_table">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="column1>Route</th>
        <th class="column2">Location</th>
        <th class="column3>Track</th>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
```

and so on..

I am using a button to call each toggle function, I will use checkboxes once I have the basic code working. So, is there a way for me to cut down the amount of code?

**EDIT: Thank you all for your answers, it was really hard to pick a single answer but i'm grateful for all your input.**

Comment: Could you add your HTML - specifically the elements where you call these functions. I would imagine you can DRY this up by using the index of the triggers.

Comment: `function tablecolumntoggle(cls){$("."+cls).toggle();}` will do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've added my basic table structure to my question.

Comment: @Bruno still you are missing the buttons and checkboxes. although the posted answers will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it dynamically using checkboxes, add a data property to the checkbox

```
<input class='toggleColumns' type="checkbox" data-target="column1" />
<input class='toggleColumns' type="checkbox" data-target="column2" />
<input class='toggleColumns' type="checkbox" data-target="column3" />
<input class='toggleColumns' type="checkbox" data-target="column4" />
```

then add a change event on the checkbox:

```
$('.toggleColumns').on('change', function (e) {
    // get the target for this checkbox and toggle it
    var tableColumn = $(e.currentTarget).data('target');
    $('.' + tableColumn).toggle();
});
```

Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Ls49w97/

Comment: I've received great answers overall but i'm choosing this as the answer because it seems more flexible. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help!, I have also added a fiddle so you can see how it is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a late addition, but to add one more alternative: if you have multiple setups of this kind and you don't want to add classes each time, you can show or hide a column with something like `$('tr *:nth-child(' + (ColumnIndex + 1) + ')', table).toggle();`. Especially if you change the column order in the future, the class approach can come to bite you.

One step further, is not to define the checkboxes beforehand, but have JQuery create them on the fly. This is also easier in maintaining the page and with the added benefit that you can assign the column index while creating the input objects and don't have to add any special attributes in design time.

All in all, the html would be as light as possible (no classes or properties) and doesn't have to be maintained. An example where the checkboxes are added in a div:

```
var table = $('table'); //add an id if necessary
var cols = $('th', table); //headers
var div = $('<div>'); //new div for checkboxes
cols.each(function(ind){    
    $('<label>').text($(this).text()).append(
        $('<input type="checkbox" checked=true>') //create new checkbox
      .change(function(){
        $('tr *:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')', table).toggle();         
      })
     ).appendTo(div);
});

table.before(div); //insert the new div before the table
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0epL68Lr/2/)

Comment: Incredibly useful! I think I shall implement this in my code as well. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You Pass number 1,2,3 function

Try this

```
function tablecolumn1toggle(id){
$(".column"+id).toggle();
}
```

function call like this

```
tablecolumn1toggle(1); or
tablecolumn1toggle(2); or
tablecolumn1toggle(3);
```

OR

```
 function tablecolumn1toggle(colum_name){
$(colum_name).toggle();
}
```

function call like this

```
tablecolumn1toggle(column1); or
tablecolumn1toggle(column2); or
tablecolumn1toggle(column3);
```

Comment: While this works, it's too inflexible, meaning you must name your columns 1,2,3 (which they are in the simplified question).  Better to pass in the full class (such as answer by AKS) then you can name them appropriately.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing that @freedomn-m mentioned. Thanks for your answer nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

```
/* number is a parameter now */
function tablecolumntoggle(i){
    $(".column"+i).toggle();
}

/* example to iteratly call */
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  tablecolumntoggle(i);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to make it simpler.

Give each button a `data-col` value and the matching column element(s) the same `data-col` value, then they can be paired in a simple function:

```
<button data-col='column1'>toggle</button>
<button data-col='total'>toggle</button>
<button data-col='other'>toggle</button>
<div class="col" data-col="column1">
   column 1
</div>
<div class="col" data-col="total">
   total column
</div>
<div class="col" data-col="other">
   other
</div>
```

and code

```
$(function() {
  $("button[data-col]").on("click", function() {
      var col = $(this).data("col");
      $(".col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();
  });
})
```

Simple fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bb1mm0cp/

Comment: great solution, I would use this but is the data-col attribute compatible on older browsers?

Comment: Yes, older versions of html allowed you to add anything you liked, so you could do `<a col="1">` but that's frowned upon these days, instead you can still add anything you like but prefix with `data-` eg `<a data-col="1">`.

Comment: It's not a `data-col` attribute, it's a `data-` attribute - you can put anything you like after `data-`, eg `data-heres-more-info` then use jquery `$(..).data("heres-more-info")`

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks so much, people like you make SO a great place to learn :)